# Specify `next` url passed to login view by Django login_required decorator

Tags: python, django

From [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) I know that when you use the `@login_required` decorator on a view, if the user is not logged Django will:

> redirect to `settings.LOGIN_URL`, passing the current absolute path in the query string.

So if the decorated view is called from the url `/foo/bar/` they would be redirected to:

```
/login/?next=/foo/bar/
```

I am wondering if there is a good way to specify the `'next'` path for a particular view instead of using the default or hardcoding it in `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`.

The way my site is currently set up (I am not sure if this is the best way to do it) I have an item detail page, and when a user tries to act on the item (i.e. `POST` form data and change the item record in the database) but they are not logged in, it redirects them to the login page.

My problem is that the path that is passed for the `next` parameter is the path for the form `POST`ing action, and I would like the user instead to be redirected to the item detail page they were previously on. Is there a way to specify which URL is passed as the `next` parameter instead of using the default or defining it in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This limitation is only applicable to the `/admin/` section of Django. You could write your own login view that redirects to where ever you want (example at the bottom of this post).

The current **admin** functionality seems to be written around the idea that the admin should always go back to the entered url that was viewed before being redirected to the login page.

To change this behaviour of the admin these are your options, as i see it.

#### Custom login_required decorator

To change the default behaviour add a next keyword arg to the login_required functionality. This would require rewriting the login_required function and user_passes_test helper function found in *django.contrib.auth.decorators*. Based on the original code it could look something like:

```
def user_passes_test(test_func, next=None, login_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user passes the given test,
    redirecting to the log-in page if necessary. The test should be a callable
    that takes the user object and returns True if the user passes.
    """

    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if test_func(request.user):
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            path = request.build_absolute_uri()
            resolved_login_url = resolve_url(login_url or settings.LOGIN_URL)
            # If the login url is the same scheme and net location then just
            # use the path as the "next" url.
            login_scheme, login_netloc = urlparse(resolved_login_url)[:2]
            current_scheme, current_netloc = urlparse(path)[:2]
            if ((not login_scheme or login_scheme == current_scheme) and
                    (not login_netloc or login_netloc == current_netloc)):
                path = request.get_full_path() 
            resolved_next_url = resolve_url(next or path)
            from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
            return redirect_to_login(
                resolved_next_url, resolved_login_url, redirect_field_name)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator


def login_required(function=None, next=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in, redirecting
    to the log-in page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_authenticated,
        next=next
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name,
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

In the code above i've added keywords args `next` and added next url resolving. Django's [original login_required can be found here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py).

This would allow you to do:

```
@login_required(next='app:view')
def profile(request):
    ....
```

#### Manual next query parameter

Alternatively you could manually create login urls with the next parameter already set, but this seems an approach that would not work in your case.

```
<a href="/login/?next=/app/view/" />Login</a>
```

#### Create a middleware that replaces the next param

If you intend to redirect to a single url - maybe a couple would be possible also -, then a middleware might be an option. Make sure to place this middleware before the AuthenticationMiddleware. A middleware would look something like:

```
class LoginNextMiddleware(object):
    redirect_url = '/app/view/'

    def process_request(self, request):
        next_url = request.GET.get('next', None)
        if next_url is not None and next_url != self.redirect_url:
            params = dict(request.GET.copy())
            del params['next']
            params['next'] = self.redirect_url
            return redirect(request.path + '?' + urlencode(params))
```

#### Write a custom login view

Finally, if you want flexibility writing a custom login view is the way to go. This would look something like:

```
def login_user(request):
    logout(request)
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:view'))
    return render_to_response('login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And would require a custom form, something like:

```
<form action="{{ request.get_full_path }}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />
  <input type="text" autofocus name="username" />
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  <button type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if my understanding is correct, the `login_url` keyword will specify where I want to redirect to if the user is not logged in. That piece works for me. What I am looking for is a way to specify the 'next' parameter so I can set the location that the user will be redirected to *after* they have been redirected to the login url and successfully logged in.  In other words, using your example, the user is redirected to `/app/login/` and after logging in they are redirected to a url I specify (if I knew how to...)

Comment: Updated the answer to match what you're looking for.

Comment: I ended up going with a solution similar to your last suggestion of a custom login view. Thanks for the detailed write-up.