# Django - login - redirect to specific url only when logged in from homepage

Tags: django, django-login

There are two scenarios of user log in:

1. Log in from homepage
2. Session expired, and user was logged out. User was forced to re-log in to stay in the current page (`@login_required` decorator is used)

With the use of `@login_required` decorator, if I don't specify `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in `settings.py`, if the user is logged off due to session expiration and logged back in, it will redirected back to its current page, like this:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/?next=/my-current-url-page/`

This is a very nice feature, and I would like to stick to it, but if I am in `Scenario 1`, it will be redirected to:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/`

I want to specify redirect url only when the user is logging in from home page. How can I set an exception for in which the user is logging in from home page?

**urls.py**

```
# this renders the home page
re_path('^$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),

# this renders the other pages
path('well_list/', decorator_include(login_required, [

    re_path(....),
    re_path(....),

    ]))
```

FYI, `decorator_include` is a code snippet that allows you to apply decorator for url patterns with `include()`.

Comment: you are using django's default login view right ?  in that case you don't have control over the redirection. for your requirement you have to write custom login view and check

Comment: do you mean *after* the user has logged in successfully from homepage?

Comment: @zerohedge yes, after the user logged in from homepage, I want to redirect it to a specific page, but only when login was directly from homepage, not due to session expiration on other pages

Comment: @NakulNarayanan do you have any link to code snippet that does that?

Comment: This may help you [custom login required decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598155/specify-next-url-passed-to-login-view-by-django-login-required-decorator)

Comment: @JPG I don't think that's what im looking for, since I'm not trying to overload the `@login_required` decorator, but instead add special `next` parameter for my `auth_views.login`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773576/django-custom-login-page this might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (adapted to creating the template and changing the variables):

view.py

```
def login_user(request):
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None and user.is_active:
    login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_DOCUMENT_REDIRECT_URL)
return render(request, 'foobar.html')
```

url.py

```
url('login', views.login_user)
```

you can now write your form for template